# How can I embed http iframe at my HTTPS website?

Tags: wordpress, http, iframe, https

Suppose I want to show another website (http:// ....) to a child page of my http website.

When it comes to execution, i find out that even
I have added this tag :

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

The page still turn me a blank page instead. Would you please tell me what else I have to work it on in order to show my http websites as iframe of my website ?

Comment: i am having the same problem i want to embed my http website in my https website did you managed to do that ?